# Cannot find module: in my app with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have problem with my app, the files' tree is:

```
myApp
 controllers
  cars.js
 models
  car.js
 app.js
 package.json
```

in my code I call my model and mi controller of the next way...

```
var express         = require('express');
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
var mongoose        = require('mongoose');
var methodOverride  = require("method-override");
var app             = express();
...

**var models = require('./models/car')(app, mongoose);**
**var CarCtrl = require('./controllers/cars');**
```

but, not working it.. I have the next error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'controllers/cars'
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'models/car'

anything idea? thank you.

Comment: I hate to be pedantic but please check that you actually have `./` in front of each of the module strings, because if you did the errors would be formatted like `Error: Cannot find module './controllers/cars'`

Comment: Which is the file, in which this code resides? app.js?

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the root first.
require('../myApp/controllers/cars'); 
If this didn't work, try console logging the path.
Hope this works

Answer (score 1):

Check both car and cars.js. If you require app.js in any of them, you created a chain dependency, which Node.js throws this exact error, that you can't find a module.